# Dual belongsTo relations with loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a couple relations I want to model,

1. A Message belongs to 2 Profile's (a sender and a recipient)
2. An Enrollment consists of a Profile and a Curriculum.

I tried to do #1 using 2 hasOne but ended up with Profile.messageId.

```
{
  "name": "Message",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "text": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "seen": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "sender": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Profile",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "recipient": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Profile",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Same problem w/ #2...

```
{
  "name": "Enrollment",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "currentPage": {
      "type": "string",
      "comments": "What page are they on in this curriculum?"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "curriculums": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Curriculum",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "profiles": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Profile",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 hasOne relations instead of a hasMany? https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasMany+relations

Comment: Should I do 2 hasMany relations with different foreignkey names (sender, recipient)?

Comment: And for the Enrollment - It will be a Through model. Profile will have a hasManyThrough relation with curriculum and visa versa. https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations

Comment: @broinjc You should try that. If that worked post it as an answer and accept it. I believe the problem is happening because you didn't specify the foreignkey so loopback is assigning the default.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat - I'll post my solution soon :) thanks for the reminder. Still working it with sample data just to make sure I've got it just how I want it.